# Can I have a rails Helper without a corresponding Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, architecture, ruby-on-rails-5, helper

It's just a doubt about Rails architecture, I have Model Notification, but I don't have the NotificationsController, and I need to use some notifications methods at my views, that's why I'm thinking creating the NotificationsHelper file. I now that maybe I could just put these methods at ApplicationHelper but this file is already very long.

So it's ok to have a Helper file without a corresponding Controller? Or not?

Comment: Short answer: **Yes**. You can create as many helpers as you want, unrelated to their models or controllers.

Comment: Yes, you can,to use helpers properties you would have to include this in corresponding controller example: - `include CustomHelper`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to note a few things. First, as they said in the comments, yes you can do that, just define it inside your `helpers` directory.

To use the methods defined in that new file in your **views** you just call them as you do with any other helper methods.

To use them inside your **controller**, there are two options.

- Include the module in your controller, (as stated in one of the comments)
- Use the method `helpers` (At least in Rails 5). That is, inside your controller, you can use any method defined in any of your helpers like this

  `class SomeController < ApplicationController
    def some_action
      helpers.some_method_from_any_helper
    end
  end`

The good thing about this second approach is that you don't have to expose unwanted methods in your controller.